Issue with VB6 calling a .bat file for large files
I’m facing an issue when executing a .bat file from a VB6 program:
My VB6 program calls a .bat file.
The .bat file contains a Java command that processes two files.
This generally works, but when one of the files exceeds a certain size, the Java command is not executed.
Interestingly, it works perfectly if I execute the .bat file by double-clicking it – regardless of the file size.
My question: What can I do to ensure that the .bat file is reliably executed through the VB6 call, regardless of the file sizes?
Thanks for your help!

Why does you VB program run a batch file rather that running the java command directly? We also need a [mcve] to properly assist you.

Is there an exit code of Java process available, and is there anything in the Java process output (stdin + stderr) ?

Thanks for your answers. The issue was that large PDF files were not fully created. Therefore, checking only for the file's existence is not sufficient; I need to ensure that the file is not currently being used by another process.

The issue was that I started the .bat file from VB while the PDF file to be processed had not yet been fully created.
The creation of the PDF file had also been initiated earlier via VB.
Before calling the .bat file, I now check whether the PDF file exists and is not locked.

Looks like this question can be closed? User resolved his own issue by the looks of it.
